# cant run powershell commands

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-web-apps

I need some help, I'm trying to configure a office web app server to connect to the farm and whenever I try to run the command it gives an error, been through the net and can't find anything or a GUI equivalent.

This is the command:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding –ServerName “server.domain.com” -AllowHTTP Set-SPWOPIZone –zone “internal-http”
$config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
$config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$config.Update()
```

and this is the error:

> New-SPWOPIBinding : The term 'New-SPWOPIBinding' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-SPWOPIBinding –ServerName “server.domain.com” -AllowHTTP Set- ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-SPWOPIBinding:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any help is appreciated please.
thanks

Solution:

I was running them on the office-web-app server, as sp13 is not installed the commands are not recognized.
It has run on the Application server, I did so and it worked.

Thanks every1 for the support...
Enjoy your weekend

Comment: Add-PsSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" before your first line of script should help. More here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/11/14/add-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-snap-in-to-all-powershell-windows.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> goto start -> all programmes -> microsoft sharepoint programmes ->
>   rightclick on sharepoint managment shell -> then click on run as
>   admin.

wait for it to load, the error indicates that the moduels havent been imported. the best way to do this is by navigating again to the same place this time when you `right click on sharepoint managment shell` you can select `pin to start menu`. now it will be under start menu at the top when you `click on the start button`. you should see a arrow pointing to the right, `click on the arror or hover over`, move to the right and click on `import system moudles`!

I would also like to note that your mixing two commands into one!

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName <String> [-Action <String>] [-AllowHTTP <SwitchParameter>] [-Application <String>] [-AssignmentCollection <SPAssignmentCollection>] [-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]] [-Extension <String>] [-FileName <String>] [-ProgId <String>] [-WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]]
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219441.aspx

```
Set-SPWOPIZone [[-Zone] <String>] [-AssignmentCollection <SPAssignmentCollection>] [-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]] [-WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]]
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219451.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

"If Windows PowerShell doesn’t recognize these cmdlets when you run them, you may need   to import the OfficeWebApps module. Use this command"

```
Import-Module -Name OfficeWebApps
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890080.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try the command as this:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding –ServerName "server.domain.com" -AllowHTTP
Set-SPWOPIZone –zone "internal-http"
$config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
$config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$config.Update()
```

The difference is having a space between the New- and Set- commands. Make sure you are refering to the right server. You can find the name of your server using `Get-SPServer` command.